# Distance between two points on a circle

Tags: geometry, tangent-line

Two circles with radius 1 are tangent to one another. One line passes through the centre of the first circle and is tangent to the second circle at the point $P$. A second line passes through the centre of the first circle and is tangent to the second circle at the point $Q$. Find the distance between $P$ and $Q$.

This question appeared in a first year calculus exam, and I can't see how I would even use my knowledge in differential calculus to try and solve this. It seems more of a geometry problem, and when I try to draw a diagram I am left at a loss because there's hardly any information given to try and solve. If someone could give me a hint as to how to begin, that'd be great. Thank you. I also wasn't too sure how to tag it, so my apologies. [image: my diagram]

Comment: Have you noticed the figure forms right triangles?

Comment: That's a terribly uninformative title.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't want to make it seem like I was just begging for the right answer.

Comment: @cgug123: You could still do that by having a flatly descriptive title such as "Distance between two tangent points on a circle" or something like that.

Comment: The problem has one trivial solution unless we can assume that the points $P$ and $Q$ are distinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the first circle be centred $A$ and second one $B$.

> Check that $\angle PAB=\angle QAB=30^\circ$ (See what the lengths of $PA$ and $PB$ are!)
>
> Also check that $PAQ$ forms an equilateral triangle

Edit:

$PA=\sqrt 3, PB=1,AB=2 $ . Let $PQ$ cut $AB$ at $D$. Triangle  $PAB, BPD, QAB,  QBD$ are similar.

$\angle PBD=\angle QBD=60^\circ$

> $\angle APD=90-\angle BPD=90^\circ-30^\circ=60$
>
> $\angle AQD=90-\angle BQD=90^\circ-30^\circ=60$

So in triangle $APQ$ all angles are $60^\circ$ and $PA=\sqrt 3$

Comment: I can see that it is, and that the angle is 60 degrees, but I don't know how to get the side lengths from there. Sorry, I'm very inexperienced in geometrical applications

Comment: @cgug123 Got the equilateral triangle?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure how to prove it is equilateral like the first answerer, however. I can just see that it is.

Comment: @cgug123 Whats $\angle BPQ$? Can youprove it is same as $\angle PAB$?

Comment: 60 degrees, yes?

Comment: @cgug123 You are wrong!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49148/discussion-between-cgug123-and-qwerty).

Comment: @cgug123 dont chat . Continue here. This discussion is completely related to the question.

Comment: Okay, sorry, the website recommended me to do that.

Comment: A line connects $A$ and $P$ right?

Comment: Aren't all equilateral triangles 60 degrees?

Comment: Yes, there is a line from A to P

Comment: @cgug123Whats $\angle PAB$?

Comment: @cgug What's $\angle PBQ$?

Comment: 30 degrees. I think it's half of the equilateral, but I'm probably mistaken?

Comment: @cgug123 You see why $\angle APQ=60^\circ$?

Comment: Visually, yes. No idea how to mathematically prove that, but the question doesn't ask for that.

Comment: @cgug123 Okay.. I don't know how to make you understand. Unless you see **mathematically** the exact angles and side-lengths of triangle $PAB$ , I can't help

Comment: I mean that I can see it and understand it I just haven't been taught the proper level of mathematical rigour and notation to write it. But otherwise I understand your point intuitively.

Comment: Please note that this is a first year computation course. My level and experience is nowhere near yours or most others.

Comment: @cgug123 If you don't know what simiar triangles are, and that angles of a triangle sum up to $180^\circ$ , you shouldn't be attempting this problem.

Comment: I know that. I just don't know how to prove it, which is what I thought you were asking me to do. Furthermore I drew my diagram freehand, to mimic the test environment meaning that no I cannot clearly and decisively see the relationship. I would also think that while I try to improve my math skills by attempting problems that are so out of my league, as you would have it, I would be supported on such a website rather than patronized and lectured.

Comment: @cgug123 The entire answer. Happy now?

Comment: What? I didn't ask you for that.

Comment: @cgug123 You essentially wanted the distance between $P$ and $Q$ right?

Comment: No I essentially did not. This question was a multiple choice question it would be fine if I got it wrong as long as I knew why. Therein lied my question

Comment: @cgug123  Thats it. You want to know **WHY** $PQ = \sqrt 3$ right?

Comment: Actually, you helped me understand what to look for and where to look. For that, thank you. I still have a trivial question about it left, and I can see that you are too incensed to properly answer.

Comment: @cgug123 NO no.. You can ask..

Comment: First, I'll add my diagram and you can tell me if it's correct. It's free hand, so I'm worried that my errors are coming from wonky shapes

Comment: Actually I need 10 reputation or something so I can't do that. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @cgug123 There you go! 11reputation

Comment: Thank you so much! I added it.

Comment: @cgug123 Now name $B$ and join $B$ to $P$ and $Q$. Your diagram is correct. See which angles are $90^\circ$

Comment: Okay I did that, the issue is that P and Q are a bit to the left of B, they're not perfectly aligned. Is that alright?

Comment: @cgug123 That is perfect. It **will be somewhat _left_** of $B$ .Did you see which angles are $90^\circ$?

Comment: Yes, APB and AQB are both right angles.It's also a special triangle, I see, with the 1, 2, root 3 side lengths, no?

Comment: Okay so using cosine law I got the root 3 answer! Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: @cgug123 I think so!.Please accept my answer, if it helped you. (Check the tick mark near the voting sign.)\

Comment: Awesome okay nice talking to you!

Comment: @cgug123 #HappyToHelp

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Make a drawing, and by considering its angles, show that the triangle $\triangle O_1PQ$ is equilateral  where $O_1$ is the centre of the first circle.

Now note that the $\triangle O_1O_2P$ is a right triangle where $O_2$ is the centre of the second circle. Then by using Pythagoras theorem we can find $O_1P$ ($=PQ$) from $O_1O_2$ and $PO_2$.

Comment: Okay this I can do! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If this is on a calculus exam, then it’s likely that you’re meant to compute the slope of the tangents to the circle via differentiation. Center one of the circles on the origin and place the center of the other circle at $C=(2,0)$.

Implicitly differentiate $x^2+y^2=1$ to obtain $dy/dx=-x/y$. The slope of the line through $P=(x,y)$ and $C$ is $(y-0)/(x-2)$. Setting these equal to each other yields the equation $$2x-x^2=y^2.$$ Combine this with the equation of the circle and solve the resulting system.